# Python only running while loop once

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, windows-10

```
import pygame

r_colour = (200, 100,100)
bg_colour = (0,175,200)
(width, height) = (600, 600)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
screen.fill(bg_colour)
pygame.draw.rect(screen, r_colour, (30, 30, 100, 100), 0)

pygame.display.flip()

running = True
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                screen.fill(bg_colour)
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, r_colour, (20, 30, 100, 100), 0)
                pygame.display.update()


if running == True:
      for event in pygame.event.get():
          if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    screen.fill(bg_colour)
                    pygame.draw.rect(screen, r_colour, (20, 30, 100, 100), 0)
                    pygame.display.update()



while running:
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
      break
      running = False



pygame.quit()
```

I am trying to get the red square to move when pressing the 's' key, not sure as to why it only moves once and then stops. Very new to programming, so I am sorry, if it's long or hard to read.

Comment: I haven't used pygame.But from what I understood,you're checking for "S" key only once (inside that "if" statement").

Comment: Rabbid76 has clearly explained what I thought! Congratulations on your first program and Welcome to stackoverflow!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A typical application has 1 single application loop. The application loop does:

- handle the events and changes states dependent on the events
- clears the display
- draw the scene
- update the display

The `KEYDOWY` event occurs once when a key is pressed, but it does not occur continuously when a key is hold down.
For a continuously movement you can get the state of the keys by [`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed):

```py
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
```

e.g. If the state of <kbd>s</kbd> is pressed can be evaluated by `keys[pygame.K_s]`.

Add coordinates (`x`, `y`) for the position of the rectangle. Continuously manipulate the position in the main application loop, when a key is pressed.

e.g.
Increment `x` if <kbd>d</kbd> is pressed and decrement `x` if <kbd>a</kbd> is pressed.
Increment `y` if <kbd>s</kbd> is pressed and decrement `y` if <kbd>w</kbd> is pressed:

```py
import pygame

r_colour = (200, 100,100)
bg_colour = (0,175,200)
(width, height) = (600, 600)
x, y = 20, 30

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))

running = True
while running:

    # handle the events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    # change coordinates
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_d]:
        x += 1
    if keys[pygame.K_a]:
        x -= 1
    if keys[pygame.K_s]:
        y += 1
    if keys[pygame.K_w]:
        y -= 1

    # clear the display
    screen.fill(bg_colour)
    # draw the scene
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, r_colour, (x, y, 100, 100), 0)
    # update the display
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```